# How much clearance do I need for cross levers?

Tags: brakes, handlebars

I'd like to put cross (interrupter) brake levers on my drop-bar tourer, but I also like to use a bar bag.  There is about 55 mm of space between my bars and the bar bag, measured horizontally.  Will cross top levers (and my hands, in order to operate them!) fit comfortably in this space?

I'm also aware that most people have their cross levers angled downwards, which thankfully must reduce the amount of horizontal clearance they require.  What angle would you recommend for this?

Comment: Angle of flat bar levers (or interrupter levers) should generally be in line with your the angle of your arms.

Comment: I doubt you will get a definitive answer here. More likely you'll have to try it for yourself and see how it fits.  If the bag is too close then you could shim it out somehow - depends on the construction on your clamps.

Comment: That's quite tight, but presumably you wouldn't direct to move your hands to these levers suddenly. For a specific model of lever a measurement could be made, then you could mock something up out of cardboard to see if that left enough room for your hands. I decided against such levers in the end so can't help with that, but a few friends have bought new bikes with them on - you might be able to measure up on a display model.